# Robots.txt disallow with variable folder name in path

Tags: robots.txt

I have several paths on server I need to disallow in robots.txt. The logic is as follows

/folder/folder/nameoffolder1/exludenext/me1/
/folder/folder/nameoffolder2/exludenext/me1/
/folder/folder/nameoffolder3/exludenext/me2/
 etc..

The question is will the rule below work for all folders after /excludenext/?

Disallow: /folder/folder/*/exludenext/*

In [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) are stated rules such as /fish*.php but would that apply for folders as if I understand it correctly this rule would not apply for /fish-tank/file.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: is there some stackseo?

Comment: Eh, should be fine here. It's a bit of a stretch to call robots.txt SEO.

Comment: The link you provide is *not* the [Robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/robots.html). It’s Googles documentation about their use of Robots.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major search engines do support `*` wildcards for URL exclusion, and [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-analysis) (Crawl > Blocked URLs) provides a tool to check your rules against sample URLs.

Instead of writing complicated rules, an alternative using HTML is to include `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` inside `<head>` on the webpages displayed at the URLs you wish to exclude from SERPs.

Comment: Is there any way how can I allow the /excludenext/ and exclude /excludenext/me1 as well as /excludenext/me1/ ? 
As the rule /folder/folder/*/exludenext/* applies for the excludenext folder as well if I add the slash then it does not apply for urls without / in the end

Comment: what i basically need is to include
/exludenext/
and exclude
/exludenext/me1 and /exludenext/me1/

Comment: For that, you will need to create two separate rules, one excluding `Disallow: /exludenext/me1` and one excluding `Disallow: /exludenext/me1/`.  A better option might be to include the following HTML inside `<head>` on the webpage displayed at the above URLs: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`